# Add More - feature for a group of input(Field Group) in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

"Add More" feature for a group of input in druapl 7

Form is built with Profile 2 Module & Field Group is used. i want user to fill the same group of inputs 'n' numbers. Similar to the below image we have another section named "Previous Project". user can add their prev project and by clicking on "Add More" same set of input fields will get another data from user.

this feature is in drupal Field Setting for individual fields only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Your question is vague, but I am assuming that you need to provide **add more functionality
for a group of fields**.  Use **Field Collection module** to add more functionality for a group of fields
https://drupal.org/project/field_collection